# Passing width & height into swf url

Tags: flash, swfobject

I need to play directly from a swf url into browser. here is my code

```
    http://website.com/flash.swf?url=http://myaudio.mps/;&autoplay=true&
    skin=test.xml&width=400&height=100
```

The audio play correctly, the problem am facing is that i can't pass on the width and height for the swf in the url.

Help please

Comment: Could you explain more your problem ? What's the problem with width and height and where you are using them ?

Comment: @akmozo
I want to use this link on browser:
`http://website.com/flash.swf?url=http://myaudio.mp3/;&autoplay=true&skin=test.xml` , it work correctly the music play from that swf player, now i want to pass the width & height of that swf player in the url,

I've tried 

http://....skin=test.xml **&width=400&height=100** 

No success, please help

Comment: If you want to set the width and the height of your swf with these params, I think that's impossible because swf will take the size of the browser's window ( there are some other methods to show your swf with these params inside a html page for example ), but if you are speaking about setting the size of an element ( an object ) inside your swf, you have just to get these params and use them ( as you did for url and autoplay params ).